# Does PHP mail only work in windows?

Tags: php

Is there any reason PHP would only work in windows?

I keep seeing 'windows only' in the documentation, but maybe I am confusing this with something else.

If it does only work in windows, why? And if not, why does all the documentation mention 'windows only' so frequently?..

Comment: No it isn't only for windows and it's probably mentioned a lot because it breaks a lot in windows due to the "nuances" of the platform

Comment: Can you post the link of the documentation you are looking at, it doesn't really make sense that php is only for windows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reason that PHP would only work in Windows. It's cross-platform.
The documentation does make references to "Windows only" but that's generally referring to a **feature** that only works on windows (it's not referring to the entire engine/interpreter).

Comment: accepting in 10 mins. i see what the people are doing here copying your answer haha. don't worry

Answer (score 2):

There are certain functions/extensions that only work on Windows or *nix because they require certain facilities that other OSes dont have. PHP as a whole works on either OS, its only some capabilities that work on one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `mail()` function works both on Windows and Linux. The reason you're seeing quite a lot of "Windows only" notes is due to the fact that some features of `mail()` are unsupported, or supported differently under windows.

`mail()`'s "proper" functionality is fully supported under Linux systems, but due to Windows doing things differently to Linux under the hood, available features change. For example, one particular note on [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes) states that:

> The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from the
>   Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for
>   composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a
>   MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the
>   localhost or a remote machine).

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is information that is only **relevant** to installation of PHP on windows machines.

For example -

> **Caution (Windows only)**
>   When PHP is talking to a SMTP server directly,
>   if a full stop is found on the start of a line, it is removed. To
>   counter-act this, replace these occurrences with a double dot.
>
> ```
> <?php $text = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $text); ?>
> ```

This **caution** message is only relevant to windows machines - it deals with new line characters that differ from *nix platforms to windows platforms.

The actual *use* of the `mail()` feature doesn't depend on the platform you use as long as the platform is capable of sending emails.